# Pulling variable from separate methods in Java

Tags: java, variables, methods

I have a simple method that collects text from a user, then puts it through another method that formats it to my liking. 
But, I want my file name to be the same as a variable that is entered in the 1st method. How do I call this method in my main method?

In short, how do I call the variable "symbol" in the method "getInfo()" so that I may insert it into my printwriter?

```java
public class FileTicketAsText {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String page = getInfo();
        String fileName = 
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName + ".txt", "UTF-8")) {
            writer.println(page);
        }
    }

    //This method will ask the user for information and pass it to the makeTicket method.
    public static String getInfo() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String z = "\r";
        System.out.print("Name? ");
        String name = sc.nextLine() + z;
        System.out.print("Symbol? ");
        String symbol = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Title? ");
        String title = sc.nextLine() + z;
        System.out.print("Summary? ");
        String summary = sc.nextLine() + z;
        System.out.print("Question? ");
        String question = sc.nextLine() + z;
        System.out.print("Answer? ");
        String answer = sc.nextLine() + z;


        return (makeTicket(name, symbol, title, summary, question, answer));

    }

    //This method will format the input given in the getInfo method and return it.
    public static String makeTicket(String n, String s, String t, String su, String q, String a) {

        String z = "\r";
        String header = z + z + "Cog241/CSC241 Fall 2014" + z + "Ticket To Demo" + z + z;
        return header + z + "Name:  " + n + z + "Assignment:  " + s + " - " + t + "\r" + "Summary..." + "\r" + su + z + z + "Question..." + z + q + z + z + "Answer..." + a;

    }


}
```

Comment: You should consider designing a class to hold the collection of all the variables/fields for a particular record (set of user responses).   Then, you can pass this object around to different parts of your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on BadZen's comment, try creating a class `Ticket`.

```
public class Ticket {
    private String name;
    private String symbol;
    private String title;
    private String summary;
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public Ticket(String name, String symbol, String title, String summary, String question, String answer) {
        // set all the variables with the arguments passed in. E.g.
        this.name = name;
    }

    // create getters and setters if you wish. If you need to use symbol, you will
    // need to create a getter for that, e.g.:

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    // You can override the default toString() method to get your ticket, 
    // or you can just call this makeTicket() instead.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String z = "\r";
        String header = z + z + "Cog241/CSC241 Fall 2014" + z + "Ticket To Demo" + z 
           + z;
        return header + z + "Name:  " + name + z + "Assignment:  " + symbol + " - " 
            + title + "\r" + "Summary..." + "\r" + summary + z + z + "Question..." 
            + z + question + z + z + "Answer..." + answer;
    }
}
```

Then you can have `getInfo()` read in the variables and create a new `Ticket` object, and return a `Ticket` instead of a `String`.

Then you can call `.getSymbol()` on your `Ticket` object to get the symbol, and `.getString()` (or `makeTicket()`, whatever you decided to call it) to get the `String` that you print out.

Comment: Also, please avoid using variable names like `s`, `n`, as it makes your code harder to read. :(

Comment: Will remember this, still getting started in Coding (as if you couldn't tell).

Answer (score 0):

Declare the "symbol" as class level variable. and set the value in the getInfo() method use the same in your main method.

```
public class FileTicketAsText {
    //Declare class level variables. use get & setter if required

    public static String symbol = "";



    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String page = getInfo();
        String fileName = 
        try  {
           PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName + ".txt", "UTF-8")
            wirtle.println(symbol);
            writer.println(page);
        }

    }

    // This method will ask the user for information and pass it to the
    // makeTicket method.
    public static String getInfo() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String z = "\r";
        System.out.print("Name? ");
        String name = sc.nextLine() + z;
        System.out.print("Symbol? ");
        symbol = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Title? ");
        String title = sc.nextLine() + z;
        System.out.print("Summary? ");
        String summary = sc.nextLine() + z;
        System.out.print("Question? ");
        String question = sc.nextLine() + z;
        System.out.print("Answer? ");
        String answer = sc.nextLine() + z;

        return (makeTicket(name, symbol, title, summary, question, answer));

    }

}
```

Comment: This gives you the error "non-static method getSymbol() cannot be referenced in a static context"

Comment: Thanks for the note I just corrected to use static variable.